# for/while loop for reading user input

Tags: javascript

I'm kinda new to programming and I got this question in a quiz. I need to write a JavaScript program to read 10 positive values from the user, and then sum only the multiples of 3 and 5.

I couldn't even finish the code. help?

```
var x = new Array ();
var total;
x.push(parseFloat(window.prompt("enter a value",""),));
for (x.length<=10; i=0; i<10; i++) {
    total += x[i]
} 
else{
    document.write(total);
}
```

Comment: I don't see any logic dealing with "multiples of 3 and 5". So what's the actual problem ..?

Comment: Consider removing the array and using: `var num = parseFloat(window.prompt("enter a value",""))`. Then do something immediately with `num` (based on some condition) and another `sum` variable. The loop determines *how many* times the user is prompted (window.prompt is such a brutal mechanism) but does not affect how the input *is used*.

Comment: You need to put your prompt inside for loop and add if statement `num % 3 == 0 || num % 5 == 0` also `for` loop don't have `else` only `if` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your prompt function inside for loop and add check if number is multiply by 3 or 5.

```
var total;
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    var num = parseFloat(window.prompt("enter a value",""));
    if (num % 3 == 0 || num % 5 == 0) {
        total += num;
    }
}      
document.write(total);
```

**UPDATE**:

```
var total;
var i = 0;
while (i<10) {
    var num = parseFloat(window.prompt("enter a value",""));
    if (num >= 0 && (num % 3 == 0 || num % 5 == 0)) {
        total += num;
        i++;
    }
}      
document.write(total);
```

Comment: i need the to ignore values<0 in the argument and still keep the count of values entered set to 10, where do i include that?

Comment: @Nouas little bit different `while` loop instead of `for`

Answer (score 0):

thanks, i did set total=0 so that after the sum it prints out a value instead of NaN

```
var total = 0;
var i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
    var num = parseFloat(window.prompt("enter a value", ""));
    if (num >= 0 && (num % 3 == 0 || num % 5 == 0)) {
        total += num;
        i++;
    }
}
document.write(total);
```